# PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: database, exception, magento2.2.4

I had installed Magento2 in Xampp earlier and now I am trying it removing xampp with local apache2, php and mysql server. I have used the backup database and the previously used Magento2 folder here.

When I tried to access the website as 127.0.0.1/magento2, I am getting the following error. But I can log in to mysql server with mysql - root -p with password correctly. What can be the reason?

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' in
>   /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:128
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(128):
>   PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', 'root', Array) #1
>   /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect() #2
>   /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(398):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect() #3
>   /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460):
>   Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_connect() #4
>   /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `store_w...', Array) #5
>   /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(517):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT`store_w...', Array) #6
>   /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(580):
>   Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('SELECT `store_w...',
>   Array) #7
>   /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737):
>   Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select),
>   Array) #8
>   /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Config/Source/RuntimeConfigSource.php(87):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select))
>
> ## 9 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Config/Source/RuntimeConfigSource.php(57):
>
> Magento\Store\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->getEntities('store_website',
>   'code') #10
>   /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/ConfigSourceAggregated.php(40):
>   Magento\Store\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->get('') #11
>   /var/www/magento2/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Config/ConfigSourceAggregated/Proxy.php(95):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated->get('') #12
>   /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Config/Type/Scopes.php(63):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated\Proxy->get() #13
>   /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(131):
>   Magento\Store\App\Config\Type\Scopes->get('websites') #14
>   /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/WebsiteRepository.php(182):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Config->get('scopes', 'websites', Array) #15
>   /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/WebsiteRepository.php(141):
>   Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteRepository->initDefaultWebsite() #16
>   /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver/Website.php(46):
>   Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteRepository->getDefault() #17
>   /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver.php(140):
>   Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver\Website->getAllowedStoreIds(NULL)
>
> ## 18 /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver.php(126):
>
> Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver->readStoresData() #19
>   /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver.php(89):
>   Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver->getStoresData() 
>   ..... and so on..

Comment: Please check the mysql access details and update those on app/etc/env.php

Comment: Check you give proper permission to user and also try with changing password.